# Remove Vec product second mutable borrow occurs here

Tags: rust

I have a list (`sprites: Vec<RefCell<Sprite>>`) in a structure

I have to add objects and remove them, no problem to add, but impossible to remove

add objects

```rust
pub fn _clean() {}
    fn create_sprite(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32) {
        let src_rect = Rect::new(0, 0, 9, 9);
        let mut sprite = Sprite::new(0, x, y, src_rect);

        self.sprites.push(RefCell::new(sprite));
        println!("{}", self.sprites.len());
    }
```

Delete objects

```rust
let mut pos: usize = 0;
        for sprite in &mut self.sprites {
            sprite.borrow_mut().x += 1.0;
            // collision sprite shoot
            if sprite.borrow_mut().x > (self.map.nbr_column as u32 * self.map.tile_wight) as f32 {
                println!("shoot out {}", pos);
                self.sprites.remove(pos);
                //self.remove_sprite(pos);
            }
            pos += 1;
        }
```

ditto if i do a `pop` instead of `remove`

---

I cleaned the code to produce an executable minumun code

```rust
use std::cell::RefCell;

pub struct Sprite {
    pub index: usize,
    pub x: f32,
    pub y: f32,
    pub vx: f32,
    pub vy: f32,
}

impl Sprite {
    pub fn new(index: usize, x: f32, y: f32) -> Sprite {
        let mut sprite: Sprite = Sprite {
            index: index,
            x: x,
            y: y,
            vx: 0.0,
            vy: 0.0,
        };
        sprite
    }
}

pub struct Game {
    sprites: Vec<RefCell<Sprite>>,
    map: f32,
}

impl Game {
    pub fn new() -> Game {
        Game {
            sprites: vec![],
            map: 30.0,
        }
    }

    pub fn update(&mut self) {
        let mut pos: usize = 0;
        self.sprites.retain(|s| {
            // s is &RefCell<Sprite>
            s.borrow_mut().x += 1.0;
            s.borrow().x <= self.map
        });
        println!("{}", self.sprites.len());
    }

    fn create_sprite(&mut self, x: f32, y: f32) {
        let mut sprite = Sprite::new(0, x, y);

        self.sprites.push(RefCell::new(sprite));
        println!("{}", self.sprites.len());
    }

    pub fn handle_event(&mut self) {
        self.create_sprite(10.0, 10.0);
        self.create_sprite(20.0, 10.0);
        self.create_sprite(30.0, 10.0);
        self.create_sprite(40.0, 10.0);
        self.create_sprite(50.0, 10.0);
        self.create_sprite(60.0, 10.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut the_game = Game::new();

    the_game.handle_event();
    the_game.update();
}
```

Comment: Please seek to make a proper [mcve]. Parts of the code are missing (what is `Sprite`, which methods are involved, etc.), which makes us unable to reproduce the issue. Moreover, the given snippets have formatting problems and contain definitions which are not relevant (e.g. `_clean`). If you can build something that shows the exact same problem in the [Rust Playground](//play.rust-lang.org), the better. The [Rust tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) provides additional tips.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I iterate a vector once and insert/remove/modify multiple elements along the way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45517170/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `for sprite in &mut self.sprites` creates a mutable borrow of the `self.sprites` collection that spans the entire loop body. This means that you cannot modify the collection itself inside the loop body, because doing so will cause the loop to become invalid.

When you attempt to call `self.sprites.remove(pos)`, this call *would* cause all sprites after `pos` to move forward by one in memory. This is forbidden because you currently have a reference to the sprite that is about to be removed, and also because the sprite at `pos + 1` would be skipped (the `remove` call moves it forward by one, but the iterator is going to move to the slot after it).

Rust provides a way to perform what your loop body is trying to do: the [`Vec::retain`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.retain) method.

```rust
self.sprites.retain(|s| { // s is &RefCell<Sprite>
    s.borrow_mut().x += 1.0;
    sprite.borrow_mut().x <= (self.map.nbr_column as u32 * self.map.tile_wight) as f32
});
```

This goes through each sprite in the list, updating it, and then returning a condition which, when `true`, tells the `Vec` to keep the sprite, and when `false`, tells the `Vec` to remove it.

Comment: Why the non-idiomatic `: &RefCell<Sprite>`?

Comment: Solely to be clear about what the `retain` closure receives

Comment: i have the some probleme with  ```s.borrow().x <= self.map``` if self.map is remplaced by value, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Thank for you help, this code works

```rust
...
let map_width = (self.map.nbr_column as u32 * self.map.tile_wight) as f32;
self.sprites.retain(|s| {
    // s is &RefCell<Sprite>
    s.borrow_mut().x += 1.0;
    s.borrow().x <= map_width
});
...
```