# How to manage ownership with mutable iterators in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator, borrowing

In Rust I'm trying to do this:

```rust
use std::ops::Index;

#[derive(Debug)]
struct TestChild<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> TestChild<'a> {
    fn new(name: &'a str) -> Self {
        Self { name }
    }

    fn add(&mut self) {
        // Some code here
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Parent<'a> {
    children: Vec<TestChild<'a>>,
}

impl<'a> Parent<'a> {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let init = TestChild::new("Init child");
        Self {
            children: vec![init],
        }
    }

    fn get_last(&self) -> &TestChild<'a> {
        self.children.index(self.children.len() - 1)
    }

    fn test(&mut self, name: &str) {
        for child in self.children.iter_mut() {
            child.add();

            println!("{:?}", self.get_last());
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Parent::new();
    p.test("Foo");
    p.test("Bar");
}
```

However, I'm getting an error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*self` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:39:30
   |
36 |         for child in self.children.iter_mut() {
   |                      ------------------------
   |                      |
   |                      mutable borrow occurs here
   |                      mutable borrow later used here
...
39 |             println!("{:?}", self.get_last());
   |                              ^^^^ immutable borrow occurs here
```

I find this error confusing because I'm not borrowing `self` as immutable inside the loop. Rather, I'm borrowing each of the `TestChild<'a>` in `self.children` as mutable. But Rust seems to think that by getting a mutable iterator for `self.children`, I'm mutating `self`. I suppose I can see the reasoning of this: `self.children` is a field on `self` after all. However, the inner immutable borrow is of a `TestChild<'a>`, and the immutable borrow is on `self` so this shouldn't cause any issues IMO. I can fix this by transforming it into two loops but that doesn't seem like a very good solution to this problem. So, how should I go about fixing it?

Comment: _"Rust seems to think that by getting a mutable iterator for `self.children`, I'm mutating `self`"_ Not really, but `self.get_last()` does borrow `self` entirely, which is incompatible with holding a mutable iterator to `self.children`.

Comment: @E_net4isoutofcommentflags So, if I understand you correctly, Rust is complaining because I'm mutably borrowing `self.children`and trying to immutably borrow `self` which involves immutably borrowing `self.children`. Or is it that by getting a mutable reference to `self.children`, I'm mutably borrowing `self`?

Comment: Both statements are inaccurate. Any method call with `&self` as the receiver will borrow `self` entirely, regardless of how the method was implemented or which parts of the struct are used underneath. However, if you can retrieve a part of the struct's value without borrowing the full struct, then those other parts are not being borrowed. The way to fix your example depends on what you really want to do. Is the `println!(` line really important in practice? Also worth reading: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45517170/1233251

Comment: @E_net4isoutofcommentflags I used the `println!` call in place of another function call which references several fields on `self` so I think I'll just have to split up the loops into a mutable one and an immutable one. If you have any other suggestions for how I might avoid doing that, however, I'd be happy to hear there