# problem trying to add a value in a vector second mutable borrow occurs here

Tags: rust

I'm starting with rust and as practice I need to go through a vector and check its values, if the value / 2 = 0 then at that moment I add any value to the vector:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut v = vec![1, 2, 3];
    {
        for i in &mut v {
            println!("{}", i);
            if *i % 2 == 0 {
                v.push(32);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But it's error to:

```
error[E0499]: cannot borrow `v` as mutable more than once at a time
 --> src/main.rs:7:17
  |
4 |         for i in &mut v {
  |                  ------
  |                  |
  |                  first mutable borrow occurs here
  |                  first borrow later used here
...
7 |                 v.push(32);
  |                 ^ second mutable borrow occurs here
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I iterate a vector once and insert/remove/modify multiple elements along the way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45517170/how-can-i-iterate-a-vector-once-and-insert-remove-modify-multiple-elements-along)

Comment: What do you expect happen if you add a value while iterating ? add 32 to the vector ? so this loop never end ? what do you want as final result ?

Comment: In general, you can't do that. In don't know any language that really allows to modify a collection while iterating it: It's UB in C++, it throws an exception in Java, C# and Python, etc.

Comment: @mcarton In Python, it's kind of valid. The iterator keeps the index it's currently at as the internal state, and if you append elements at the end, the iterator will hit them as well.

Comment: well, you can do it in rust too, https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=517188389c3411bfa631389eb59728ab